# Problem Adding to NSMutableArray in Loop

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, nsarray, nsnumber, sigabrt

I'm not sure what the problem is with this loop exactly, but I keep getting SIGABRT whenever I run it. According to the log the problem is when I try to add the NSNumber to the NSMutable array near the end of the loop. Obviously I've made an elementary error but I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
NSArray *toArray = [ourDictionary objectForKey:toString];
NSMutableArray *allValuesMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while (done == NO)
{
    if (i == 10)
        done = YES;
           /* 
            *The job here is to multiply these three numbers together and store the 
            *product in the mutable array. It tells me NSObject did not recognize selector
            *and then crashes.
            *original and multiplyFrom are always the same value, and multiplyTo is updated
            *from an array I made above from a p-list.
            *I'm hoping I didn't make a ton of rookie mistakes here, but I'm new to dealing with
            *NSMutableArray and such.
            */

    NSNumber *original = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:convertThis];
    NSNumber *multiplyFrom = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:multiply];
    NSNumber *multiplyTo = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[toArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]];
    NSNumber *product = [[NSNumber alloc] init];

    product = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:([original doubleValue] * 
                                          [multiplyFrom doubleValue] *
                                          [multiplyTo doubleValue])];

    [allValuesMArray addObject:product];
            //This line ^^^ causes crash
    i++;
}
NSArray *returnThisArray = allValuesMArray;
[allValuesMArray autorelease];
return returnThisArray;
```

Comment: Can you add the log history over here?

Comment: Please show more code, specifically the creation of `allValuesMArray`. Also, remove `[product release]`, that will cause a crash later on. And lastly, the proper constants for the BOOL type are `YES`/`NO`, not `TRUE`/`FALSE`

Comment: I've edited the code to show more of what's going on, if it still isn't enough just let me know what else you need to see. Everything above the loop should work fine, I am not sure exactly the best method of getting what I want. The point of this method is to read a list of numbers from the toArray, compute the product, store each product into a new array which will then be returned and written to a p-list.

Comment: Please remove that [allValuesMArray release] line — as _several_ people have pointed out now, it's wrong! Plus you are leaking an NSNumber from "product = [[NSNumber alloc] init]". BTW: Is there a reason why you don't use a simple for-loop?

Comment: I just like while loops better, is there a performance tradeoff or is it just code simplicity?

Comment: The for loop simply is much more readable and succinct. Yes, _your_ while-loop actually is less efficient than a for-loop would be, because you have two compares instead of one and an additional stack-variable to store to...but that is _before_ compilation. Plus that absolutely pales in comparison to what happens _inside_ the loop, where you create **four** NSNumber-s (one of which you're leaking) that you don't put to use in the code you showed.

Answer (score 0):

You are releasing the allValuesMArray: [ allValuesMArray release];

Since the retain count is 0 at this point, this will free the array immediately.

Try using [ allValuesMArray autorelease ]. This will release the array in the future, giving the opportunity for the calling method to use the unreleased array or retain the array for later use.

Also you could check if product is not nil before you add it to the array.

And you've got a memory leak.

product = [[NSNumber alloc] init];

then you assign it a different object later on.

Comment: I had autorelease before I made a mistake when I was copying it over, my problem is inside the loop, specifically the line [allValuesMArray addObject:product];

Comment: Are you sure product is not nil? What is the double value of [original doubleValue] * [multiplyFrom doubleValue] * [multiplyTo doubleValue]?

Comment: that seems to work, for instance if I assign ([original doubleValue] * [multiplyFrom doubleValue] * [multiplyTo doubleValue]) to a double it gives me an answer, but I'm afraid that for some reason I'm not understanding the proper way to add objects to a mutable array...

Comment: I mean, no matter what I try adding to that array it causes a crash; I just tried adding an NSString with a hardcoded constant and it still crashed: NSString *testString = @"This is a test"; [allValuesMArray addObject:productString]; sigabrt

Comment: NSString *testString = @"This is a test"; [allValuesMArray addObject:productString]; -- Sorry... testString is not getting added to allValuesMArray... productString is.

Comment: yeah, another typo, sorry; I've been awake for like 19 hours and I should just be using copy/paste rather than clicking between windows... anyways I eventually got this to work the way I wanted after all, the most important lesson I learned from this is to go to sleep rather than stay up late trying to add extra features, and I'm really surprised that I made all those memory leaks normally I'm really conscious of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is a typo, but you're not allocating a pointer and not even a type of `NSMutableArray`, but of type `NSArray`. Check line no. 2:

```
NSMutableArray allValuesMArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

It should be

```
NSMutableArray *allValuesMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: @Justin Then please take the time and fix it. Both of them!

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating an NSArray and assigning it to an NSMutableArray? Perhaps you meant the following:

```
NSMutableArray* allValuesMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code in a cleaned-up, non-leaking form:

```
NSMutableArray *convertedValues = [NSMutableArray array];
// moved outside of the loop and descriptively named:
double normalizedValue = convertThis * multiply;
// make use of NSFastEnumeration -- better readability _and_ reliability
for ( NSNumber *scaleFactor in [ourDictionary objectForKey:toString] )
{
    // just in case you want to add a breakpoint to see if everything works as expected:
    double convertedValue = normalizedValue * [scaleFactor doubleValue];
    [convertedValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:convertedValue]];
}
return convertedValues;
```

If something goes wrong with this code, I bet that the array returned by `[ourDictionary objectForKey:toString]` contains at least one instance that isn't an NSNumber — which you will recognize by an `NSException` being thrown at `[scaleFactor doubleValue]`.